# Why isn't my PHP working in my search box

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my search bar to link to a specific page when a user enters something I have this.. Keep in mind this isn't my whole code but it's giving me this error...

Notice: Undefined index: link in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd1_vtec_0100348514\pages\search.php on line 63

```
<?php 
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
session_start();
//checks if the login session is true
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---


 include ('header.php'); ?> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css">
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db("wd1_vtec_0100348514") or die(mysql_error());

?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 3;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles
            WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what I'm looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

       if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop



echo "<p><a href='".$results['text']."'><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</‌​p>";
    }

}
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    echo "No results";
}

}

else{ // if query length is less than minimum
echo "Minimum length  is ".$min_length;
}

?>
</body>
<a class="btn btn-search" type="button" href="home.php" >Search Again</a>
</html>






       <div style="float:right">  <a class="btn btn-danger logout" href="logout.php" > Logout</a> </div>

        <div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.php" target="_self" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Sessions</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Session 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="session2.php" target="_self" >Session 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="session3.php" target="_self" >Session 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="session4.php" target="_self" >Session 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="session5.php" target="_self" >Session 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="session6.php" target="_self" >Session 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="session7.php" target="_self" >Session 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="session8.php" target="_self" >Session 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="session9.php" target="_self" >Session 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="session10.php" target="_self" >Session 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="session11.php" target="_self" >Session 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="session12.php" target="_self" >Session 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="session13.php" target="_self" >Session 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="session14.php" target="_self" >Session 14</a></li>



            </ul>
            <li><a href="blog.php" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>


    </ul>

    </div>

    <?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What is in your `$results`?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele I am wanting it to link to a page but for some reason it's not letting me do so

Comment: Do some debugging: use `var_dump($results); die()` immediately before your echo to see what it actually contains

Comment: @Sarah It's not letting you because there is no `link` in your `$results` array.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele I've looked in my DB and found a column that I want to link it to which has a name of '1' but now it's showing me a 404

Comment: please check  your code. its have syntax  error. and  there is no corresponding if condition of last else condition.  please check

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply check if there is column `link` in your database. You show us one error what means that other columns (title and text) exist

You shouldn't also use `mysql` functions any more. They are deprecated. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Thanks for your help I've found in my column theres an ID called 1 so I used that but now it's giving me a 404 error.

Comment: So it seems you create incorrect link or your PHP script doesn't work well. We don't know what's your site structure. And if ID for your link will be valid. Maybe you should add `/` at the beginning or use other column.

Comment: you should append some page name before the ID

Comment: @Khushboo wait.. Why?

Comment: can you please echo your ID and paste the result here ?

Comment: @Khushboo I've just also tried fixing it but still no luck

Comment: @Sarah Why you use `$results['text']` to create link to the article? It's text and it rather should be used to create anchor

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I thought that's how it should be done?

Comment: no... in which column you have link in database? Please add that in href

Comment: @Khushboo I've linked it to the table session and have gone to sessionID name with the ID of '1'. That's what I've done basically

Comment: but you are using Articles table to fetch the searched result. so, what exactly you want to display? Show that thing